# Какую технологию или сервис можно использовать для обработки, аналитики больших данных на PHP?

Tags: php, анализ-данных, big-data

**Всем привет.**

Есть файл например xls или текстовый файл в котором 100 тыс. и более строк.

**Вопрос.**
Какую службу или технологию можно использовать чтобы например я этот файл передал допустим на сервер по API там ее обработал и получил результат.

Перечитал уже тона информациии о Hadoop, Apache Spark.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать.

**Спасибо.**

Comment: 100 тысяч — это очень и очень мало, влезет в оперативку любого домашнего компьютера. Зачем здесь какие-то службы и технологии?

Comment: microsoft azure